# javascript replacing special characters

Tags: javascript

is it possible to translate special characters like ®, ü etc with javascript String replace function?

Comment: You might want to use `"\xDD"` or `"\uDDDD"` instead of the actual character, to make it more readable and manageable for most editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, and is as simple as can be:

```
'®'.replace('®','anything');
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure is!

Running this in the Firebug console

```
"®ü".replace(/[®ü]/g,"replaced")
```

returned

"replacedreplaced"

You can also do

```
"®ü".replace(/[\xAE\xFC]/g,"Wohoo! ");
```

which returns

```
"Wohoo! Wohoo! "
```

A good hex symbol lookup page can be found at http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

---

**Example**

running this jQuery on this page

```
$(".post-text").text().replace(/®/g," ******** ")
```

returns

```
" is it possible to translate special characters like ******** , ü etc with javascript 
String replace function? Use this syntax... string.replace(/\xCC/g/,''); Where 'CC' is 
the hex character code for the char you are wanting to replace. In this example I am 
replacing with empty string ''. yes, and is as simple as can be: ' ******** '.replace('
 ******** ','anything'); Sure is! Running this in the Firebug console " ******** ü".
replace(/[ ******** ü]/g,"replaced") returned replacedreplaced "
```

Comment: +1, If you're going to downvote, at least give a reason. This answer does what's asked and gives nice examples. Very thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax...

```
string.replace(/\xCC/g,'');
```

Where 'CC' is the hex character code for the char you are wanting to replace. In this example I am replacing with empty string ''.

Specifically for the characters listed in the question:

```
string.replace(/[\xAE\xFC]/g,'');
```

Comment: Running this on this page in the console doesn't return expected results.

Comment: @El, ah! You have an extra forward slash after the global flag. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

(yes, I know this question is old, but it still came up high in Google when I was looking for something specific, so the comment/answer might be helpful for some people):

Previous posters have told you how to replace single characters. I'd like to add that this is generally not a good idea (there are exceptions, of course), because there are so many possible "special characters" that you have to think of. You'll just end up adding more and more replacements and you'll still miss some.

It's generally easier and safer to look for one of the built-in functions to do this that will take of *all* characters that need special handling.

In your question, you don't tell us what you need it for - but I guess 3 years later, this is more for other people with similar problems anyway:

If you want to pass a string as a parameter, it's best to use the `encodeURIComponent` function. Also look at [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for that.

If you want to encode other things, it's always best to find a built-in function that does it for you. Maybe http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/ or http://shebang.mintern.net/foolproof-html-escaping-in-javascript/ (somewhat verbose, but with good explanation of things you should *not* do) will help

Answer (score -1):

Use this JavaScript statement to replace all the special characters from a string

```
var a1 = $('#txt').val().replace(/[^\x30-\x39\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A\x20\x26\x28\x29\x2C\x27\x22\x2E\x2F\x26\x40\x5C\x7C\x3A\x2D]/g, '');
```

The above statement will replace other than in the set  0-9A-Za-z &(),'"./&@\|:-  with a nothing i.e. deletes any control characters etc.

Still Better option is to replace all character(s) other than ASCII character set. i.e.

```
 var a1 = $('#txt').val().replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '');
```

ASCII character set starts from space i.e. \x20 and ends on tilde ~ i.e. \x7E. So replace all other characters; other than ASCII.

FYI: just in case if you don't know ^ sign is used indicate other than the set or character given.

Comment: @alberto sorry I mistakenly given php solution to remove special characters, hope you would not negatively vote against me this time :)

Comment: For php this will be $rec = preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/', '', trim($rec)); this will remove all the non printable characters from the variable.